# How to expose Linkerd Viz Dashboard via Ingress AWS Application Load balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, aws-application-load-balancer, linkerd

I already installed Linkerd on a Kubernetes cluster that is runing in AWS: [Linkerd - Getting Started](https://linkerd.io/2.11/getting-started/)

All checks are ok, but I cannot see the viz dashboard in my local:

```
kubectl -n linkerd-viz port-forward svc/web 8084
```

Is there a way to expose it via ingress ALB?

Answer (score 3):

You can expose the dashboard in a couple ways. You can modify the web service to add an external load balancer, which will respect any AWS annotations you already use with AWS load balancers. You can also create the appropriate routing rules for your existing ingress. You can find some examples here: https://linkerd.io/2.11/tasks/exposing-dashboard/

Answer (score 0):

Refer https://linkerd.io/2.14/tasks/exposing-dashboard/#tweaking-host-requirement. You need to remove "enforced-host" from spec.container.args from deployment of "web".
Follow:

1. linkerd viz install > linkerd-viz-install.yaml
2. Update inkerd-viz-install.yaml commenting out the line:
   "- -enforced-host=^(localhost|127.0.0.1|web.linkerd-viz.svc.cluster.local|web.linkerd-viz.svc|[::1])(:\d+)?$"
3. kubectl apply -f linkerd-viz-install.yaml